# Oracle Query to List Words Found in Pseudo Column

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Is it possible to search a text field in an Oracle table for a set of word (ie, salary, bank, building, etc.) and have Oracle place the word or words it found in a pseudo column?

Comment: I suggest that showing a diagram on what you need to do, might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how sophisticated you want the search to be. For example:

- simple substring match

  ```
  SELECT text_column, 'salary' my_pseudo_column
  FROM mytable
  WHERE LOWER(text_column) LIKE '%salary%';
  ```
- Oracle TEXT query (assuming you've added the text index)

  ```
  SELECT text_column, 'salary' my_pseudo_column
  FROM mytable
  WHERE CONTAINS(text_column, 'salary') > 0;
  ```